# How to compare the dates within the column and based on the latest dates, print other corresponding columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ProductId, PriceType, Price, FromDate columns.

in this, Product ID is list of ids given to different products, pricetype is the category of different prices like deal price, wholesale price etc., Price is money values of each products.

Currently, for each product ids there are multiple pricetypes & fromdates.
[Click here for the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFymJ.jpg)

I want a final output where for every product Id there should be unique price for every price type category based on the latest FromDate.

Example, for Product id 221, there are 2 list price with 2 different values in price and fromdate. now my final output should be product id as 221, fromdate as 01/07/2014, price as 19.8 and pricetype as list price.

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow and i am sorry, i really dont know how to do whatever you have asked me to. i have attached a picture in my original question. i have added the query below which i have been trying.  **'Select * into #temp1 from (select ProductPrices.ProductId,ProductPrices.FromDate,ProductPrices.Price,PriceTypes.Id,PriceTypes.Name as pricetype 
from ProductPrices left outer join PriceTypes on ProductPrices.PriceTypeId = PriceTypes.Id) as x'**

Comment: see the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i am getting output for the query mentioned in the previous comment. but i am stuck in this query **'Select #temp1.ProductId, #temp1.pricetype, max(FromDate) as Fromdate, #temp1.Price from #temp1 group by FromDate'**

Comment: please look at the link  provided.

Comment: i am getting this error message **Column '#temp1.ProductId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT ProductId, PriceType, Price, t.FromDate , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY ProductId, PriceType ORDER BY Fromdate DESC) AS RowIndex
    FROM #ActualData 
)
SELECT ProductId, PriceType, Price, FromDate
FROM temp t WHERE t.RowIndex = 1
```

Comment: Thank you TriV. I tried your query as well but was not able to get an output. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

@TriV's answer should work.  Here is another option.  You'll have to try them both to see which performs better on your data.

```
select t.ProductId, t.PriceType, t.Price, t.FromDate
from #temp1 t
where exists(select 1
             from #temp1 t2
             where t2.ProductId = t.ProductId
             and t2.PriceType = t.PriceType
             group by t2.ProductId, t2.PriceType
             having t.FromDate = max(t2.fromDate))
```

Comment: Hi Jerrad.. thanks for your response. sorry for being dumb but i am new to SQL as well. here in the above query you mentioned 't.ProductId' is it equal to '#temp1.ProductId' per my original comment? also is 'MyTable t' equal to '#temp1'? what does t2 mean here?!

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer to use your #temp1 table name.  "t2" is an alias for #temp1, used in the subquery in the `where` clause.  It is used to differentiate that usage of #temp1 from the #temp1 in the outer query (which is aliased as "t").

Comment: Thank you so much Jerrad. You are a savior. it is working and i got the output. i have been struggling with this for past 4 days. thanks once again. you made my day.